# how to make a GET httpwebrequest in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

i was trying to make a form navigating program and i wanted to know how to make a GET httpwebrequest here is the code i use for a POST httpwebrequest

```
Dim postData As String = "lsd=AVrFBNXT&display=&enable_profile_selector=&legacy_return=1&next=&profile_selector_ids=&trynum=1&timezone=-120&lgnrnd=163248_FehM&lgnjs=1372203160&email=" & (TextBox1.Text) & "&pass=" & (TextBox2.Text) & "f&default_persistent=1"
Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer
Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php"), HttpWebRequest)
postreq.Method = "POST"
postreq.KeepAlive = True
postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
postreq.Referer = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php"
postreq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
Dim postreqstream As Stream = postreq.GetRequestStream()
postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
postreqstream.Close()
Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
logincookie = tempcookies
Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Method to "GET" and drop the request stream:

```
Dim postData As String = "lsd=AVrFBNXT&display=&enable_profile_selector=&legacy_return=1&next=&profile_selector_ids=&trynum=1&timezone=-120&lgnrnd=163248_FehM&lgnjs=1372203160&email=" & (TextBox1.Text) & "&pass=" & (TextBox2.Text) & "f&default_persistent=1"
Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer
Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php"), HttpWebRequest)
postreq.Method = "GET"
postreq.KeepAlive = True
postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
postreq.Referer = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php"
Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
logincookie = tempcookies
Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
```

Comment: Something is missing here, I see that postData is encoded into byteData, but byteData is not being used anywhere, so how does the postData get sent in the request?